# Joining 2 Tables where one is a specific column and the other is a string?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I asked this yesterday, but I think I need to clarify a few things. I appreciate everyone's help here!

Basically, my goal is to join 2 tables through a "middle table" where the the shared values  with one of the tables is in the description column which is a bunch of text.

---

If I have **SportsTable** with player_column And then there's **NewsTable** with a description_column but which contains a players name...

So **SportsTable** with player_column with "Lebron James" with **NewsTable** with a description_column of "The leading scorer in the game was Lebron James."

Can I join these two?

The responses I got were for a specific name in the LIKE CONCAT ("Lebron James") but I'm looking to get *all* the player names that are present in **SportsTable** (so, "Lebron James", "Michael Jordan", etc") that are *also* present in the description string column in **NewsTable**.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are you able to join 2 tables on a column and column text/string clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459281/are-you-able-to-join-2-tables-on-a-column-and-column-text-string-clause)

Comment: Please do not post duplicates of your question. Instead have a browse through the [tour] to see how this site works, and have a read through [ask] to arrive at a better question.

Comment: Not a duplicate - a clarification!

Comment: You should clarify in the original question.

Comment: Cool, and that will refresh and get new answers! Sounds good!

Comment: try to explain better , also you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: cool, I'll update the original question! (see above!)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
with SportsTable as (
    select 'Lebron James' as player_column  union all 
    select 'Tom Brady'  union all 
    select 'Michael Jordan'
),
NewsTable as (
    select 'I love Lebron James' as description_column  union all 
    select 'Tom Brady is the GOAT'  union all 
    select 'Lebron James and Michael Jordan are good at basketball'
)
select
    description_column,
    player_column
from SportsTable 
cross join NewsTable
where description_column like concat('%',player_column,'%')
order by 1
```